# Why does my mustache "file to string" conversion throw an undefined exception?

Tags: node.js, exception, mustache

I'm pretty new to server-side javascript. I wanted to create my first test website using node.js (v8.9.4) and mustache.js within Visual Studio Code (1.20.0) and encountered a problem. When I run my main.js and try to access the site, my data.toString('utf8') statement on line 31 throws an "undefined" exception. But when I debug it, it's defined as it should be as Buffer and displays correctly.

My limited knowledge prevents me somehow from finding the reason or at least a hint. Therefore I am grateful if you could help me with my problem. Thank you very much.

```
var mustache = require('mustache');

var model = 
{
    title: 'Mustache', 
    messages: 
    [
        'Mustache is a handy templating language.'
      , 'It goes well with JavaScript.'
      , 'It also goes well with Node.js.'
      , 'It even goes well with Scala!'
      , 'Here it\'s used to generate server-side HTML.'
    ]
}

var http = require('http');
var port = 8081;
var fs   = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) 
{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    function respond(html) 
    {
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    }

    fs.readFile('template.mustache', function(err, data)
    {
        var template = data.toString('utf8');
        var html = mustache.to_html(template, model);
        respond(html);
    });
})

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server listens: 127.0.0.1:" + port);
```

My Mustache template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>{{#messages}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/messages}}</ul>
```

Comment: `fs.readFile('template.mustache', function(err, data) { if (err) throw err; ...`

Comment: Thank you very much Aikon. After I changed my structure according to your suggestion, I was able to solve the problem. Which was as well a stupid as a simple one. The path to my file was incorrect and your structure debunked it. Thank you so much and have a nice day!!!